# Meteor job-collection not running remote jobs

Tags: meteor, job-scheduling, meteor-collections

With [vsivsi:job-collection](https://github.com/vsivsi/meteor-job-collection), I've set up jobs like in [the example](https://github.com/vsivsi/meteor-job-collection-playground), but the difference is my jobs are processed on the server. And I can't see what's missing compared to the example app, which processes jobs on the client.

> lib/db.coffee

```
@ParsingJobs = JobCollection('parsing', {
    workTimeout: 10000
    transform: (d) ->
        try
            res = new Job(ParsingJobs, d)
        catch e
            res = d
        return res
})

if Meteor.isServer
    Meteor.startup(->
        ParsingJobs.allow({
            admin: (user_id, method, params) ->
                # commented temporarily Roles.userIsInRole(Meteor.user(), ['admin'])
                true
        })

        ParsingJobs.startJobServer()
```

> server.coffee

```
que = ParsingJobs.processJobs('parsing', {workTimeout: 10000}, (job, cb) ->
    # do some processing
    job.done('success')
    cb()

ParsingJobs.find({type: 'parsing', status: 'ready'}).observe
    added: ->
        que.trigger()
```

> **On the client** I can just run a shell command:

```
x = ParsingJobs.find().fetch()[0]
x.rerun()
```

Result:

> job_class.js:16 Uncaught Error: Job remote method call error, no valid invocation method found.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Change this line:

```
que = ParsingJobs.processJobs('parsing', {workTimeout: 10000}, (job, cb) ->
```

to this:

```
que = Job.processJobs('parsing', {workTimeout: 10000}, (job, cb) ->
```